# What's the alternative of JsonObject in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, json

Am trying to develop a Wp8 app of an existing windows store app, in which JsonObject of windows.data.Json namespace is used. But am unable to use it in my wp8 app. So what is the alternative for JsonObject in Wp8 apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First step to use with ease JSON in your app is to download the NuGet package **JSON.net**. Then you just define model with proper DataContract attributes and you can then serialize and deserialize json strings quite simply using the **JsonConvert** class:
[Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

DataContractJsonSerializer is what you are looking for. It works for both Windows store apps and Windows phone apps and eliminates the need for a third party library.

If your json is like this:

```
{"name":"Bob","description":"Friend"}
```

Then you must create a 'DataContract' class to represent the json data exactly like this:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Info
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can deserialize from the json string data to the object like this:

```
    Info info;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Info));
        info = (Info)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
```

I have used this many times and it works well for arrays and nested classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to my problem. I have placed the windows store app code in a winmd file and added its reference to my WP 8 app. Now I can access the Windows.Data.Json from my WP 8 app!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json which is most popular .net Json library
[Newtonsoft.json nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)